# Finding a % from two values in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in a database which holds a value for space used, and a value for space available. What I want to do is find the % of used / free space.

```sql
select
  datetime AS "time",
  storage.name as metric,
  (used_disk_size / (available_disk_size + used_disk_size))*100 as "Total disk space"
from
  usage
inner join storage on usage.storage_id = storage.storage_id;
```

When I run the above I get 0s in all columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely the data types are integers. And a division of integers stays an integer. Cast one or all of the operands to `decimal`.

```
...
(used_disk_size::decimal / (available_disk_size::decimal + used_disk_size::decimal)) * 100 ...
```

Comment: you only need to cast one of the columns, e.g. Using `used_disk_size::decimal` would be enough

Comment: Yes, that's right and why I wrote "one or all" (or actually an arbitrary number greater that or equal one would be even more correct). I just like to be verbose in such cases and therefore cast all of them.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the problem.